# How to convert comma separated variable values to row in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a variable in my stored procedure `@param varchar', the parameter value will be like '333,445,443,222' or '555'

I need to store into as row in the `#Employee` table, `Code` column.

Expected output:

`#Employee` temp table:

```
Code
----
333
445
443
222
```

Comment: What is your expected output from the given string (provide more sample input string)? and what is your SQL server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work with any SQL server version. User define table function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString
(
  @Value     nvarchar(max),
  @Delim    nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Value, [Number],
      CHARINDEX(@Delim, @Value + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
    FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
      FROM sys.all_columns) AS x WHERE Number <= LEN(@Value)
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @Value, [Number], DATALENGTH(@Delim)/2) = @Delim
    ) AS y
  );
```

and then it can be used

```
DECLARE @param varchar(1000)
SET @param = '333,445,443,222'

SELECT value AS Code FROM dbo.SplitString(@param, ',');
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/89486

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL Server 2016, there has been a built-in function to do this:

```
select s.value
from string_split(@param, ',') s
```

I would recommend using it.  The one downside to `string_split()` is that it does not provide ordering in the string.  If ordering is important and there are no duplicates, then `charindex()` can be used.  If there can be duplicates, then I recommend a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) (need to know about [`maxrecursion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-maxrecursion-to-cancel-a-statement)):

```
create function my_split(@s nvarchar(max), @d nvarchar(1))
  returns table return
    with
      r as (
        select
          iif(p > 0, left(@s, p - 1), @s) as s,
          iif(p > 0, right(@s, len(@s) - p), '') as r
        from (select charindex(@d, @s)) as a(p)
        union all
        select
          iif(p > 0, left(r, p - 1), r),
          iif(p > 0, right(r, len(r) - p), '')
        from r
        cross apply (select charindex(@d, r)) as a(p)
        where r != ''
      )
    select s from r;
```

Output:

```
+----+-----------------+------+
|    |      param      | code |
+----+-----------------+------+
|  1 | 333,445,443,222 |  333 |
|  2 | 333,445,443,222 |  445 |
|  3 | 333,445,443,222 |  443 |
|  4 | 333,445,443,222 |  222 |
|  5 | 555             |  555 |
+----+-----------------+------+
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/HWMHS7718).