# Split a string column to single column and sort

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I was writing a function to split comma separated column, and list the values in a single column and count them.

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE stri 
(name varchar(100))
INSERT INTO stri 
VALUES ('a1, a2, a9, a8')
```

I would use this to split the values, however I need them in a single column. I was considering pivoting, and complicated it as I want the result be sorted in ascending.

```
SELECT 
     REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(name), ',', '.'), 1)) AS name1
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(name), ',', '.'), 2)) AS name2
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(name), ',', '.'), 3)) AS name3
   ,REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(name), ',', '.'), 4)) AS name4
FROM dbo.stri;
GO
```

The above query displays

```
name1 name2 name3 name4
a1    a2    a9    a8
```

The result I expect is:

```
     name
          a1
          a2
          a8
          a9

           4 -- count
```

Any guide is appreciated.

Comment: Comma-seperated columns are about as evil as it gets for database schema design. Save yourself a bunch of trouble and **don't do this**. Instead, add an additional table with two columns: one for the primary key from the original table, and one for a single value from your comma separated list. This new table can then have several rows for each row from the original table.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is what I'm trying to do. stuck on populating the new table with separated values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma separated variable values to row in SQL Server 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619081/how-to-convert-comma-separated-variable-values-to-row-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: You're still trying to deal with comma-separated data in SQL. The best way to handle this is by separating the data in the client language, **before** any SQL is involved.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SQL Server 2016 or above, you can use `string_split` like below:

```
select trim(value)
from stri A
outer apply string_split(A.[name], ',')
order by 1
```

You can count the records using the CTE on the above query.

If you are using SQL Server 2014, you can use the `XML` method like below:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))) Result
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE([Name], ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
    FROM STRI
) AS A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)
ORDER BY 1
```

db<>fiddle [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b7a8c76f9072e8568859a33e3221334)

Please check more details **[here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)**.

Comment: I'm using 2014. Thanks though.

Comment: @lije Thanks! I have updated the answer for SQL 2014 as well.